# Apache make authorization have precedence over authentication

Tags: apache-2.4

Our website has been mirrored recently and so,
I'm trying to:

- exclude a live mirror called badmirror.com
- setup a basic authentication for mysite called mysite.com

I've first managed to expulse the badmirror.com using this expression in my virtual host:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com *.mysite.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /myphp/mysite/www
        <Directory "/myphp/mysite/www">
        Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require expr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(.*)mysite\.com/"
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ling/all.log

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So basically this line does the trick:

```
Require expr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(.*)mysite\.com/"
```

With this in place, it works fine: I go to badmirror.com and it has a forbidden page, and I go to mysite.com and it shows the website.

Now I've added a basic auth on top of that in my site, using the .htaccess file in my app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>


#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *


AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /leeapp/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Problem is: now I go to badmirror.com, it asks me to authenticate,
I authenticate and now I see the content of mysite.com.

So basically, it's as if being a valid-user bypassed my other rule

```
Require expr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(.*)mysite\.com/"
```

How can I make the HTTP_HOST expression rule more solid? or at least make the authentication not override the rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it on the very comprehensive apache doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html.

So in my case I just needed to combine the Require directives in a RequireAll directive, that did the trick for me:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com *.mysite.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /myphp/mysite/www
        <Directory "/myphp/mysite/www">
            <RequireAll>
                Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require expr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(.*)mysite\.com/"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Password Required"
                AuthUserFile /leeapp/www/.htpasswd
                Require valid-user
            </RequireAll>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ling/all.log

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```